# Does findFragmentById take in a FrameLayout rather than a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragment-manager

I'm new to the concept of `Fragments`

In the video I was watching, they used this piece of code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_container);

        if(fragment == null){
            fragment = new FragmentMain();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.my_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
```

To create a `Fragment` via java.

1. In `findFragmentById` they passed in a `FrameLayout`(my_container) rather than a `Fragment`. I read in the docs that you can pass in a container id, but it confuses me how it will initialize it as a `Fragment`. How does this work?
2. Should I use `FragmentManager`? I read in the docs that it's deprecated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In `findFragmentById` they passed in a `FrameLayout(my_container)` rather than a Fragment. I read in the docs that you can pass in a container id, but it confuses me how it will initialize it as a Fragment. How does this work?

You can think of the container as of a placeholder that can hold a fragment at a time; initially it has no fragment and in this case the `if(fragment == null)` will be met, so you can do a fragment transaction (So, the container layout now is replaced by a fragment view, which is another xml layout assigned to this particular fragment and returned by its `onCreateView()` callback.`onCreateView()` is one of fragment's lifecycle callbacks that get called by the system until the fragment is fully visible to the user in the placeholder.

Later on when you want this placeholder to hold another fragment, you can do the transaction again where it repeats the same thing with the new fragment, the placeholder will show up the layout of the new fragment, and the lifecycle methods of this fragment will get called

> Should I use `FragmentManager`? I read in the docs that it's deprecated.

[`FragmentManger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager) (from `android.app` package) and its `getFragmentManager()` are deprecated, and you should use [`FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager) (from `androidx.fragment.app` package) and  `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead like you already did.

For more info you can have a look to [FragmentManager doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager) and [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

1. It will look into the container with the given ID and give you the `Fragment` that is currently inside. At no point does `findFragmentById` **initialize** a `Fragment`, it will only look through existing ones, as the name suggests.
2. You should not use the native [`FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager) on new versions of Android, as it has been deprecated, but the [`FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager) from the [AndroidX Fragment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) library, providing the same functionality.
   See also: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager